# Insert variable value into column with : separator

Tags: linux, shell

I've got an text file filled with this sample value:

```
 1:0:0:﻿Monitoring stuff with Zabbix/OCS:24 HOURS
```

So I'd like to change the second field with one variable. I'm  trying to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PRIOR="Priority = 1 - Must have | 2 - Nice to have | 3 - Interesting | 0 - Not interesting"

while read -r line;
do
echo $line
echo $PRIOR
echo -n "Set your priority: "
read SETP</dev/tty
echo "Priority defined: "$SETP
<change my 2nd column value with $SETP>
done < courses.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's one way

```
newline=$( echo "$line" | sed "s/:[^:]\+/:$SETP/")
```

that will replace the first colon followed by non-colon characters with a colon and the user's input.

Some code review notes:

- get in the habit of using good indentation -- your future self will thank you for writing readable and maintainable code
- don't use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES, leave those for the shell -- one day you'll write `read PATH` and then wonder why your script is broken.

  - `priorities="..."`, `read setp`, etc
- [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667) -- do that **always** unless you know exactly when to leave them unquoted.

  - `echo "$line"`
  - `echo "Priority defined: $setp"` -- variable inside the quotes
- validate the user's input:

  - `if [[ $setp == *[^0-9]* ]]; then echo "digits only! try again"; fi`
- in bash you can write `read -p "Set your priority: " setp < /dev/tty` -- don't need a separate echo statement
- knowing the data structures your language supports is important -- learn how to use bash arrays.

Comment: Nice, thank you glenn for answer and code review, I'll take note about that in my next scripts.